# I tried using Springboot3 and using sqlite for file storage, and then packaged it into an exe through Graalvm to run on Windows

Tags: sqlite

It is possible to run the service directly, but after packaging it into exe and clicking 'allow', the program will exit in seconds

I want to run this program

Used pom
`

4.0.0

```
<groupId>top.jc</groupId>
<artifactId>examination</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--嵌入式数据库-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--ORM-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-community-dialects</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- 引入thymeleaf模板引擎 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
            <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

application.yml
`server:
port: 5283
spring:

## Database Configuration

datasource:
name: sqlite3
driverClassName: org.sqlite.JDBC
url: jdbc:sqlite:./database.db
jpa:
database-platform: org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect
hibernate:
ddl-auto: update
show-sql: true`